# USB mouse buttons mapped incorrectly - how can I remap?

Tags: usb, mouse

At work, I have been assigned a new Macbook pro M2 running Ventura (13.4.1).  The problem is that my personal mouse (a Roccat Kone XTD) does not work with the Macbook.  I have tried a couple other mice (generic Logitech and Microsoft mice) and they both work perfectly.  The trackpad also works fine.

Specifically, the issue is that the button mapping for the Roccat mouse seems to be incorrect.  Left click, right click, and middle click all seem to do nothing.  Scrolling down triggers a right click.  Scrolling up seems to do nothing.  The "forward" button triggers a right click.  The "back" button seems to do nothing.

Of course, this Roccat mouse works perfectly with all other devices I've tried it with (Linux & Windows laptops & desktops).  How can I remap buttons for this mouse within MacOS so that it works correctly?  I have admin privileges on this laptop and I am comfortable using a terminal if either of those things help.

Comment: I would start by looking at Karabinier Elements - one of its programs reports exactly what the mac is receiving from the mouse, another of its programs might allow you to remap them. However macOS usually just works with at least right/left click. Do you have to install a driver with other OSs, does the mouse work in other macs?

Comment: @mmmmmm - it looks like the control panel software in Windows directly remaps what the mouse actually sends & saves it internally to the mouse itself, rather than remapping 'live' in the OS. That means it could be sending absolutely anything. It does look like it might be a job for Karabiner.

Comment: No, there is no driver necessary for this mouse.  There is a configuration utility (or rather there was one, it's no longer available nor installed on any of my computers).  The configuration itself is stored on the mouse; the mouse sends normal mouse events over USB.  I did find Karabiner as well as a similar CLI utility which both showed the mouse sending the same events as reported in the question (i.e. nothing for most of the buttons, mouse 3 for scroll & forward, etc.).

Comment: I got this figured out.  Was an issue with the mouse.  See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was a problem with the mouse itself.  The firmware and configuration for the mouse got wiped out - coincidentally but suspiciously at the exact same time as I swapped the mouse from my personal computer to my work Macbook.

As mentioned in the comments to the question, the configuration utility for this mouse is no longer available from the manufacturer.  I managed to find source code and build instructions for an abandoned 3rd party configuration utility for Linux called "roccat-tools".  After a couple hours tweaking build options and compiling, I got the utility running on my personal Linux desktop.  I used the utility to perform a factory reset on the mouse and it's working great now.

I am suspicious that maybe Macos attempted to configure the mouse when it got plugged in to the Macbook and this resulted in the mouse getting wiped (I frequently get popups in Macos when I plug in USB devices asking if I want to configure them; I always answer "no").  I tried unplugging and re-plugging the mouse several times as well as restarting the Macbook to see if I could trigger this issue again, but the mouse hasn't had any issues yet.

In any case, at least I now have access to the configuration utility in case this happens again.  But I wouldn't be surprised if I end up having to replace this mouse in the future if the firmware and/or mapping gets wiped again and I am no longer able to compile or otherwise use the roccat-tools utility.

Comment: Macs don"t configure mice or any USB thing on simple attachment. The default settup of most things just works with macOS so macOS does not need to do any setting up. What devices ask do you need to configure them - I have not seen many do this.